# Wait until page loads in webbrowser control 

Tags: c#, browser

I'm using the C# WebBrowswer control and I have a problem that when a button like "Next" is pressed when the page is not loaded yet the program tries to proceed but instead gives me a null error.

**Is there is a function to make the program wait until the page has completed loading?**

I tried to put a while loop in the program that checks the title of the html page but then the program freezes. Something like will freeze the program:

```
    while(!webbrowser1.Document.Title.ToString().Equals("NextPageTitle"))
   {
   }
   ::NextCommands::
```

---

It Doesnt work, i tried that and the button "fblqf" is not clicked. but its not returns null error..

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q").SetAttribute("value", "חחח");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnK").InvokeMember("Click");
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;


}
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do the work you need to do now that that page has completed loading
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("fblqf").InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Solution:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q").SetAttribute("value", "חחח");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnK").InvokeMember("Click");
    int x=0;
    while (x==0)
   {
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        if(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext") != null)
        break;
   }

    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext").InvokeMember("Click");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q").Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found an easy Solution!!!

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q").SetAttribute("value", "חחח");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnK").InvokeMember("Click");

    while (true)
   {
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        if(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext") != null)
        break;
   }

    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext").InvokeMember("Click");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q").Focus();
}
```

Comment: Do you really need that x? Couldn'y you put webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pnnext") == null inside the while condition?

Comment: You are probably right, as you can see this was one of my first piece of code.

Answer (score 7):

You need to hook the [WebBrowswer.DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event:

Perhaps in your constructor or your OnLoad:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q").SetAttribute("value", "חחח"); 
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted; 
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnK").InvokeMember("Click");
```

Then you event looks like this:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do the work you need to do now that that page has completed loading
}
```

Comment: @user1335131, I've updated my code. You should be setting up your event handler before you try to load the next web page.

Comment: interesting, at first I was tempted to say this should be the answer but i took another look and think maybe he has a valid solution to problem that could happen if an element in the page is created by startup script and doesn't exist until some time after the DocumentCompleted event occurs.