# Execute several methods

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, browser

How to execute several methods, but each method have to wait until the previous load a web page?
exemple:

```
methode1(){
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://test.com");
}
methode2(){
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://test2.com");
}

methode1();
methode2();
```

Comment: You need to add more detail.

Comment: I'd love to know who upvoted this question.

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I have update my question please help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10166832/1967056

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Run async another method, which execute several methods synchronously

```
methode1(){
   webBrowser1.Navigate("http://test.com");
}
methode2(){
   webBrowser1.Navigate("http://test2.com");
}

public void BatchRun()
{
   methode1(); // run sync
   methode2(); // run sync after Method1
}

// ...

Action toRun = BatchRun;
toRun.BeginInvoke(null, null); // Run async
```

Comment: They're still running one after the other.